# How to implement MVP Passive View?

Tags: java, mvp

I'm currently working on a desktop application using JavaFX (Please note that I'm not using the Screen Builder, I create my view directly in the coding). I would like to implement the Passive View variant of the MVP (Model View Presenter) pattern.

As I could not find any clear examples.. I tried to create a basic setup by myself.

**Main Classs**

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Model model = new Model();
        View view = new View(stage);
        Presenter presenter = new Presenter(model, view);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class Model {

    private StringProperty labelText;

    public Model() {
        this.labelText = new SimpleStringProperty();
    }

    public String getLabelText() {
        return labelText.get();
    }

    public StringProperty labelTextProperty() {
        return labelText;
    }

    public void setLabelText(String labelText) {
        this.labelText.set(labelText);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
public class View {

    private Button button;
    private Label label;

    public View(Stage stage) {

        label = new Label("This is a test");
        label.setLayoutX(50);
        label.setLayoutY(50);
        button = new Button("Click me");
        button.setLayoutX(200);
        button.setLayoutY(50);

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.getChildren().addAll(label, button);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 400, 200); //Standard size 1200, 800
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public Button getButton() {
        return button;
    }

    public void setButton(Button button) {
        this.button = button;
    }

    public Label getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(Label label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

**Presenter**

```
public class Presenter implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    private Model model;
    private View view;

    public Presenter(Model model, View view) {
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;

        //Register action listener for button
        this.view.getButton().setOnAction(this);

        //Register change listeners of model
        this.model.labelTextProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                //Update view
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

        if (event.getSource() == this.view.getButton()) {
            //Update model
        }
    }
}
```

I thought the following things should be considered when implementing a passive view pattern:

- Model and View are completely separated
- View creates and displays only the UI elements
- Model contains the data of the application and the logic to change this data
- Presenter updates the model as well as the view
- Presenter registers action event listeners and updates the model if required (View -> Presenter -> Model)
- Presenter listens to changes of the model and updates the view if required (Model -> Presenter -> View)

Using these information, I tried to build this basic structure for a model-view-presenter setup. Did I implement the passive view correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Looks OK to me. Not sure what the passive in MVP refers to. So the answer to your question is, yes, you seem to have done it right.